# Apply function to dataframes in Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written some code to rename column headers on a data frame from a row after import from a CSV file

```
df=df[1:]
new_header = df.iloc[0]
df=df[1:]
df.columns = new_header
```

I have created a dictionary of multiple CSV files (I came from R, so this seems like a R list to me):

```
ddict = {}
for file in os.listdir(cwd):
    if file.endswith("1000.csv"):
        name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        ddict[name] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(cwd, file)).T
```

Finally, I am trying to run the "rename column headers" code mentioned above with:

```
for v dict.items(ddict):
    v=v[1:]
    new_header = v.iloc[0]
    v=v[1:]
    v.columns = new_header
```

Doing so returns:

```
  File "<ipython-input-218-d301718399b2>", line 1
for v dict.items(ddict):
         ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've also tried setting:

```
define header_function():
v=v[1:]
new_header = v.iloc[1]
v=v[1:]
```

and then calling the function on V, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sparky Correct Syntax:  for key,value in dict.items(ddict):

Comment: Rakesh and @Yserbius, thanks for pointing that out. Now unfortunately I get a 'tuple' object has no attribute 'iloc'. I'm trying to make a example, but have some difficulty mapping out the datasets.

Answer (score 0):

```
for v dict.items(ddict):
```

Should be

```
for v in dict.items(ddict):
```